# cURL and ActiveMQ

Tags: http, curl, activemq-classic

I need an example on how to read/write to an ActiveMQ queue over HTTP in C or C++ using cURL (or something else, I'm open to anything at this point).
I have working code in C#, but it doesn't help.
Any help is appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**First I assume:**

- You are running activemq 5.5.0
- You are using the default activemq configuration that enables the [web-console](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html)

  - Test it by pointing a browser to http://localhost:8161/admin
- By cURL you mean libcurl and a command line example is sufficient

**Example**:

- Create a queue named test, set the body to hello world.

  - Note: [clientId] this a unique string to identify your subscribe otherwise a new consumer will be created for each request see [REST](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html)
  - `$ curl -d 'body="Hello World"' "http://localhost:8161/demo/message/test?type=queue&clientId=consumerA"`
- Pop the message of the queue

  - `$ curl -X delete "http://localhost:8161/demo/message/test?type=queue&clientId=consumerA"`
  - You should see `"Hello World"`
- Finally unsubscribe from the queue

  - `$ curl -d 'action=unsubscribe' "http://localhost:8161/demo/message/test?type=queue&clientId=consumerA"`

You should be able to monitor all of the above operations from the [admin](http://localhost:8161/admin) interface

Comment: For people using more recent versions, be sure to read the linked page: http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html as the API changed a bit (e.g. now you need `/api/` and `-u admin:admin`).

Answer (score 0):

> Until version 5.8, REST API was part of the Web Samples and was mapped
>   to http://localhost:8161/demo/message url. From 5.8 onwards, the API
>   is available by default at http://localhost:8161/api/message url

http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html